# Clean way to assign conditional dict values without repeating dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on my python and design pattern skills trying to model a game out.

A character can have a hierarchical rank so wanted to use an Enum to specify ranks like:

```
class Ranks(Enum):
   BEGINNER = 0
   MID = 1
   ADVANCED = 2
```

Based on that rank a different set of starting abilities is assigned, so I wanted to add a property to the enum class:

```
class Ranks(Enum):
   BEGINNER = 0
   MID = 1
   ADVANCED = 2

   @property
   def raw_abilities(self):
      abilities = {}
      if self.value == 0:
         abilities = {
            'will': 1,
            'health': 1
         }
      elif self.value == 1:
         ....etc

      return abilities

   @property
   def special_abilities(self):
      abilities = {}
      if self.value == 0:
         abilities = {
            'resources': 1,
            'circles': 1
         }
      elif self.value == 1:
         ....etc

      return abilities
```

This repetitive *n * ranks* code doesn't seem very elegant.  Is there a better way to describe that.

Considerations:

- other abilities/skills will be added later.  This enum class simply carries a starting point for a Character class.

Comment: You can create a dictionary which maps each rank to a sub-dictionary with all abilities and their values for this rank. In the property code you can then retrieve the appropriate sub-dictionary and create a new dictionary from it only containing the abilities related to the property (raw abilities, special abilities,...).

Comment: Use `__new__` according to the docs

Comment: Thanks for your comments!  @Bharel, I think you're saying that in case I want to add a new rank, correct?

Comment: @MichaelButscher good idea.  I think there is an answer below like that.

Comment: @StephenLloyd Yes, both answers show similar approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple answer in this case is to mainatain a map of rank -> abilities (dictionary), like so:

```
rank_to_abilities = {
    BEGINNER: {
            'will': 1,
            'health': 1
         },
    MID: {
            'will': 2,
            'health': 2
         }
    ADVANCED: {
            'will': 3,
            'health': 3
         }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
@property
def raw_abilities(self):
    return rank_to_abilities[self.rank]
```

Encapsulated within the enum (I wouldn't do this):

```
class Ranks(Enum):
   BEGINNER = 0
   MID = 1
   ADVANCED = 2
   
   @property
   def abilites(self):
        return {
            Ranks.BEGINNER.value: {
                    'will': 1,
                    'health': 1
                 },
            Ranks.MID.value: {
                    'will': 2,
                    'health': 2
                 },
            Ranks.ADVANCED.value: {
                    'will': 3,
                    'health': 3
                 }
            }[self.value]
```

Comment: I assumed that this intended the key values to be the Enum members, however, I can't get it to work with rank_to_abilities inside the class.  I have to move it out and do something like rank_to_abilities = { Ranks.BEGINNER....}.  Then within the class I can use return rank_abilities[self].  But this doesn't feel encapsulated.  What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to encapsulate the dictionary within the enum class neatly. It can be done with a method/property which computes the dictionary each time, but it's not very clean IMO. Personally, I'd just place the dictionary in the same file as the enum class itself and give it an ALL_CAPS name. Feels very clear to me. I did edit my answer to show the alternative, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
from enum import Enum


class Ranks(Enum):
    BEGINNER = (0, {'will': 1, 'health': 1})
    MID = (1, {'will': 2, 'health': 2})
    ADVANCED = (2, {'will': 3, 'health': 3})

    def __init__(self, v1, v2):
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2

    @property
    def raw_abilities(self):
        return self.v2
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet